# Query Fetch Column PDO is not working

Tags: php, database, pdo

I've got some code that needs to work.

But although connection is ok, I can't get it to work

This is code:

`$dbh = newPDO(data);
$v = $dbh->query('SELECT COUNT(1) as num FROM wia_administratorzy')->fetchColumn();`

I've got error:**Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchColumn() on boolean**

Please explain what is not working here.

Comment: PHP docs: `PDO::query()` returns a `PDOStatement` object, or `FALSE` on failure. It seems your query failed to execute.

Comment: `PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.` so you have an error with `on boolean` so you query returns not a PDOStatement object (it returns false).

Comment: Should I use prepare? Then Execute? Or what? This query works good for MySQL